# Rewriting C# from .net 4.5.2 to .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have written a few toy projects in C# using Visual Studio 2015 RC and the Winforms project template. I am trying to get my employer to use these to improve on the current Excel docs that are being used and for another process that we don't currently have a tool for.

The target machines are running Windows XP which only seems to support .Net 2.0 and I had chosen to use .Net 4.5.2, as a result the apps will not run. I have searched Google and stackoverflow, but the answers I can find only seem to reference scaling the .Net version up and not down.

Is there a more simple way of "converting" the projects from v4 to v2 than needing to design the GUI's again etc?

Comment: The bigger problem will be removing any v4.5 features like `async`, LINQ, etc. Can't you just install .NET 4.5 on the target machines? It runs on XP (just isn't installed by default).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET .NET 4.5 is not supported on Windows XP. per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp.aspx.  Only .NET 4.0 is.

Comment: You don't mention what code you are having issues with.  Since VS can change .NET targets fairly easily, its unclear what the issue is.

Comment: In what way does changing the .NET version force the GUI to be redesigned?

Comment: I stand corrected, still, downgrading from 4.5 to 4 will be way easier than 2.

Comment: thank you all, I twigged after Sam Axe's comment. I was searching for the wrong thing. I found the answer at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St for anyone who might be unsure. I think :/

Comment: @johara That's not what you should be using. That's changing the C# language version, not the .NET Framework version. The C# language version won't cause any problems for you. You can use C# 6.0 with .NET 2.0 (or 4.0), and your applications can still run on XP. The .NET Framework version can be changed using the same Properties option, though.

Comment: @hvd Thank you. I see it now, under Properties, Application, Target Framework. Much appreciated

Comment: @johara why don't you change the target framework version (right click your project file and go to properties, should be in there) and just fix the breakages. There shouldn't be many devastating issues, provided you're not using a lot of .NET 3+ libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Visual Studio will the developers be using? The same version as you or an older version?

If the same version, it is easy to fix: Open the solution and look at the properties of all projects. Reset the target framework to 2.0 on all projects and attempt to compile. Fix any errors, which will most likely be new features in .NET that 2.0 does not contain.

Older version? You have more work, as there are syntax tweaks (syntactical sugar) in each version of C#. The fastest way is switch framework locally, fix any issues, and then open the code in the same version of Visual Studio they are using. You will then go through another fix cycle to remove newer syntax.

A PITA? For sure, but not as bad as a friend of mine who inherited an ASP.NET web app where the source code left with the developer. ;-)

As for redesigning GUI, I am not sure what the issue here is, unless you are using new GUI elements not available in .NET 2/4. If so, you have to remove and use older counterparts. But anything completely incompatible should be found when changing Framework versions.

Comment: by using a new GUI, I had meant essentially building a new project as I wasn't aware it was so simple to change the target framework. Thank you for a quick response all :)

Comment: @Graffito - I would not put any stock in XP, unless it is absolutely necessary, as you are dealing with an OS that is past end of service. For the OP, 3.5 might be a temporary compromise, of course, but the business has to bite the bullet at some time, especially if they are in a regulated industry.

Comment: I just menionned the info on framework versions working on XP systems to complete your response, in order to reduce framework compatibility problems.

Comment: @Graffito - thank you then. I have been working with the hell of getting clients off XP, Visual Basic, etc, so I may come off a bit touchy on this subject. ;-)